# websocket client program always gives error

Tags: sockets, serversocket

I am trying to learn web socket API programming in python and I am running a server code and client code on my computer but I always get an error.

**The server code that I am running is:**

```
import socket      

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)     
host = socket.gethostname()                      
port = 2727                       
server.bind(('', port))             
server.listen(5)            
while True:
    c, addr = server.accept()   
    print 'Got connection from', addr
    data = c.recv(4096)
    if not data: break
    c.send(data)

c.close()
```

**The client code is:**

```
import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 2727
client.connect((host, port))
client.send('helllo')
print client.recv(4096)
client.close
```

**The error that always comes up is:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Python27\FILES\simpleclient.py", line 9, in 
>       print client.recv(4096)
>   error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Any help fixing this problem would be greatly appreciated!